# What is the difference between standard errors using the inverse of hessian and calculated using the the inverse of hessian and Fisher information?

Tags: survival, standard-error, fisher-information, hessian, frailty

In one of R packages for advanced survival analysis, the frailtypack, the output contains standard errors calculated in two ways, named: H (using the inverse of Hessian) and HIH (`H-1 * I * H-1;` where I is the Fisher Information). The values are quite close. I am wondering what the two are telling me in general (I suppose this is an universal method, not bound solely to this package and method) and which one should be reported by default (and when)?

Comment: The second appears to be the *sandwich* estimator, which is a heteroskedasticity-consistent estimator of the standard errors.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity-consistent_standard_errors for a description in the context of linear regression.   It's intended to correct for the effects of heteroskedasticity on the estimated standard errors.

Comment: It does a lot of sense. I saw this previously in the context of the GEE model, where it reported both "naive" and "robust" SEs. The structure (like a sandwich wrapping the Fisher information) resembles that. I wasn't sure, however, if this is just a coincidence... Thank you for your answer!